# Can't get specific rows in oracle sql developer

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I wanna get all SubPerimeter that have only the two criteria IDENT ('00000028', '0029428A') and no other criteria, my request doesn't seem to work as expected

```
    WITH VALID_CRITERIA AS (
    SELECT criteria.CRI_KEY, criteria.BPRM_KEY, criteria.SPRM_KEY FROM S_CRITERIA criteria
    WHERE 
        (
          criteria.CRI_TYPE = 'IDENT' 
          and criteria.CRI_VALUE IN ('00000028', '0029428A')
        ) 
    )
    SELECT 
        subP1.SPRM_IDENTIFIER, 
        subP1.SPRM_KEY
      FROM 
        S_SUB_PERIMETER subP1 
        INNER JOIN VALID_CRITERIA criteria ON criteria.SPRM_KEY = subP1.SPRM_KEY 
        and not exists (
            select 1
            from S4C_CRITERIA cri 
            INNER JOIN VALID_CRITERIA valCri ON cri.CRI_KEY != valCri.CRI_KEY
            and cri.SPRM_KEY = subP1.SPRM_KEY 
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option; read comments within code.

Sample data:

```
SQL> with s_criteria (cri_key, cri_value) as
  2    (select 1, '00000028' from dual union all  -- this key contains exactly what you want:
  3     select 1, '0029428A' from dual union all  -- only these two values
  4     --
  5     select 2, '00000028' from dual union all  -- this key contains only one value, so it doesn't fit
  6     --
  7     select 3, '00000028' from dual union all  -- this key contains both values you want,
  8     select 3, '0029428A' from dual union all  -- but it contains additional value so it
  9     select 3, '12345678' from dual union all  -- doesn't fit either
 10     --
 11     select 4, '98765432' from dual            -- this key doesn't contain any of desired values
 12    )
```

Query:

```
 13  select cri_key
 14  from s_criteria
 15  group by cri_key
 16  having count(distinct cri_value) = 2         -- only 2 (distinct) values are allowed:
 17     and min(cri_value) = '00000028'           -- one of them is this ...
 18     and max(cri_value) = '0029428A';          -- ... and another one is this

   CRI_KEY
----------
         1

SQL>
```